# Parsing a YYYY-MM-DD date strictly on Linux

Tags: linux, posix, strptime

POSIX defines a handy function, `strptime`, that can be used for parsing dates and times. Thus, theoretically, if I have a date of the format "YYYY-MM-DD", I should be able to use `strptime` to parse it like this:

```
char myDate[] = "2012-01-01";

struct tm result;
char *end = strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d", &result);
```

… and get it back out in its canonical representation with:

```
if (end != NULL)
{
    char outDate[11];
    strftime(outDate, sizeof(outDate), "%Y-%m-%d", &result);
    printf("%s\n", outDate);
}
else
    printf("Invalid date\n");
```

On OS X and Linux, this prints out 2012-01-01. So far so good! However, let's say my input date is in the wrong format: 01-01-2012.

If I run the above code again, on OS X, I get "Invalid date", which is expected. However, on Linux, I get 1-01-20 — January 20th, 1 (yes, year one).

OS X follows the specifiers strictly, parsing a string as `%Y` *only* where a four-digit year exists. Linux takes a few liberties, though, and interprets two digits as a year — it doesn't even appear that it assumes it's 2001, it treats it as year 1!

This can be worked around by changing my `if` statement to something like

```
if (end != NULL && *end == '\0')
```

… but that seems hokey. Does anyone know if it's possible to make `strptime` on Linux behave more strictly, and fail for `%Y` if the input string does not have a four-digit year?

Comment: ... I don't see why you don't like "`if (end && *end == '\0')`", that's exactly the idiom for checking that functions like `strptime` (also `strtol` and friends) have consumed the entire string.

Comment: In retrospect, I suppose this somewhat makes sense: OS X treats `%Y` as "four-digit year," Linux treats `%Y` as "full year, up to four digits", neither of which is wrong, but which definitely result in different behavior.

I guess what I'm looking for, though is a way to specify an explicit width in the format specifier, if that's possible.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that.  I would write my own parser in this circumstance, but I am a parser nerd.

Comment: After doing some tests, I've verified that %Y accepts less than 4 digits years. So I can only think of testing also `end - myDate == 10` for this case, which would mean that the 10 needed chars (for "YYYY-MM-DD") were consumed. But not perfect.

Comment: Actually I am a little disappointed to see how you noticed that Linux seems to define `%Y` as "full year, up to 4 digits". I tested, and it's true! This means it has a Y10k bug! It didn't accept my test date from the year 12101 :-( As for your impression that testing to make sure there was no garbage at the end of the string, I agree with @Zack: it's not hokey at all, it's practically essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to change strptime()'s behavior or to specify a length within the format string. (I had a look into the sources in glibc-2.3, strptime discards format modifiers and field width, so something like "%04Y" wont change a thing).

But as was already pointed out in the comments, there is nothing wrong with `if (end != NULL && *end == '\0')`. I'd recommend to use just that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is to find the index of the first dash, and use one mask or the other according to its value.